# Is there a way to recover folder which is deleted from sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, recover, delete-directory

I am using sublime text 3 in Ubuntu 16.04 Rather than clicking *Find in Folder*, I accidentally clicked *Delete Folder*. how to restore that folder. Please help.

Comment: The default version of that command attempts to put deleted items in your Trash, so whatever Ubuntu uses as the Trash/Recycle Bin is where you should check for your missing data.

Comment: I am unable to find that folder in Trash.